# What happens when I connect Tropico 4 with my Facebook and Twitter accounts?

Tags: tropico-4

There's a setting in the options panel that allows me to connect my Facebook and Twitter accounts with the game. I assume this will allow you to post about your achievements in-game. Is this correct? Does this unlock any other functionality that might be useful to gameplay?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It allows you to share short text blurbs about achievements, mission completions and some in-game events (e.g. elections) to Twitter and Facebook, and also post screenshots to Facebook.

(Note that we never auto-post; Facebook/twitter buttons appear on some dialogs, and you have to click them to post.)

Comment: Cool, an "official" answer.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: +1, Why can't *everyone* ask before posting something for you like this?

Comment: I especially like that you can remove the facebook & twitter buttons from the game with a setting! +1

Answer (score -4):

Nothing, it will fail to connect every time.